# Largest Value in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to print the largest value from an array set but I keep getting an out of bounds error.  I am unsure of how exactly fix it.  Here is my code:

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Please enter the name of the input file: ");
String inputFileName = console.nextLine();

Scanner in = null;

try {
    in = new Scanner(new File(inputFileName));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.print("Error!");
    e.printStackTrace();
}

int n = in.nextInt();
double[] array = new double[n];

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = in.nextDouble();
}

console.close();

double largest = array[n]; // Exception occurs here
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (array[i] > largest) {
        largest = array[i];
    }
}

System.out.println("The largest value in the data is: " + largest);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
double largest = array[n];
```

to

```
double largest = array[0];
```

`array[n]` causes the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, since `n` is not a valid index of your array.

This will also allow you to change

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
```

Comment: That could result in a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` too, if the array has zero length. A safe alternative for all array lengths would be `double largest = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` (or checking that the array is non-zero length, of course).

Comment: @AndyTurner or you can add a validation that requires n to be positive, since otherwise this entire code is pointless.

Answer (score 3):

Unless You have asked to do it manually , 
You can also (easily) use the built in function Arrays.sort(array);
which sorts the array and then access the largest element(the last one in the array) :

```
double[] array = new double[n];
Arrays.sort(array);
double maxValue = array[array.length-1];
```